# Displaying links in google maps infowindow for multiple markers using Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with multiple markers of companies using google maps API v3. I need to link from the infowindow to the company show view of my application, so if I click on the marker an infowindow opens with some basic information and a link to view the details of the company. The code is this:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController

...

def businessmap
    @city = City.find(params[:id])
    @mapcenter = @city.geocode
    @businesses = @city.businesses
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @businesses.to_json(:only => [:id, :business_name, :phone, :latitude, :longitude]) }
    end
  end
end
```

The mapview itself is here:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :charset => "utf-8", :src => "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false&region=IN"}
%script{:type => "text/javascript"}
  function initialize() {

  var cityLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
  = @mapcenter[0]
  ,
  = @mapcenter[1]
  );

  var options = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: cityLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  $.getJSON('businessmap.json', function(businesses) {
  $(businesses).each(function() {
  var business = this;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: business.business_name + '<br/>' + 'Phone: ' + business.phone
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(business.latitude, business.longitude),
  map: map,
  icon: image
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  });
  });
  }

%body{ :onload => "initialize()" }
  %div#map_canvas{:style => "width: 900px; height: 600px;"}
```

So, now there is just the name and the phone number, how can I display an additional link (or make the name of the business appear as a link)? The link itself is e.g. "http://localhost:3000/businesses/186-Cityname-businessname" (defined with to_param).

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relavent code you're looking to modify is is the snippet below, where `content` is getting assigned to whatever will show up in the infowindow when it's clicked on.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: business.business_name + '<br/>' + 'Phone: ' + business.phone
});
```

The trick is going to be building the URL, since the JavaScript has no knowledge of Rails routes.  You could change the controller's [JSON rendering](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) to include the URL perhaps adding `:methods => [:to_param]` *(the better way)* OR build a compatible URL in javascript *(the easy way)* and hoping that whatever parses the URLs only uses the integers.

---

**Easy Way**

In the view -

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '<a href="/businesses/' + business.id + '">' + business.business_name + '</a><br/>' + 'Phone: ' + business.phone
});
```

---

**Slightly Better Way**

In the controller -

```
format.json { render :json => @businesses.to_json(:only => [:id, :business_name, :phone, :latitude, :longitude], :methods => [:to_param]) }
```

In the view -

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '<a href="/businesses/' + business.to_param + '">' + business.business_name + '</a><br/>' + 'Phone: ' + business.phone
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the links method in javascript:
here is how you cold do it

```
var str = ( 8.8.8.8).toString().link("www.google.com");
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: str
 });
```